# Proper syntax for array.forEach() in coffeescript

Tags: node.js, syntax, coffeescript

I have a following code in coffeescript to recursively list directories (converted from javascript):

```
fs = require 'fs'

walk = (dir, done) ->
  results = []
  fs.readdir dir, (err, list) ->
    return done(err) if err
    pending = list.length
    return done(null, results) unless pending
    list.forEach (file) ->
      file = "#{dir}\\#{file}"
      fs.stat file, (err, stat) ->
        if stat and stat.isDirectory()
          walk file, (err, res) ->
            results = results.concat(res)
            done null, results  unless --pending
        else
          results.push file
          done null, results  unless --pending

walk __dirname, (err, results) ->
  throw err if err
  console.log results
```

As you can see I am using `list.forEach (file) ->` and it's working. But when I try to replace it with `for file in list` then it doesn't work properly. What do I do wrong?

Comment: Can we see what the code looks like when you change it to for file in list?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're defining a function in a loop. A common pitfall in JS. You'll need to close over the iterator.

`for file in list then do (file) =>`

Comment: The fat arrow is not necessary in this case, as there is no access to `this` inside the loop. Also, an alternative to using the `do` CoffeeScript construct, that just creates function and invokes it right there to create a new scope, is to do that yourself: for example: `processFile file for file in list`, where `processFile` does exactly the same as inside the loop. I think that alternative is clearer most of the time.

Comment: Thank a lot, it works just fine. As you advised I am using an alternative because it clearer